# Don't decrypt this encrypted string

Tags: cipher

**WARNING: Do not decrypt this encrypted string with a line of numbers.**

```
74911594191049118937910391059409111911391129122911091309129911791199509122911895391439121912991399369103912691339629151912991319140967913991549152971914191459163915791469779156914491619819152914998491669152987914296791369919175916591839184996917791649189919091879173919391869170917791149178910991849196919091849114916991239207911891909205920791879211921091909210912791949212910891759198920591349209920292099227922092059148921391439228922792179147921992349236922191529236922392219246915792369224923691619228923492499247923591679252924192469149915092279174926292489247924991799254925992479254918492569252918792599271927992809192926992609267919692829264927392009255920992939204928892889289929792959275929591909265928092869287929592189309929893099304922393009291929892279300929493119313930193039305931393019318921692179273932393159325931392459330931393139314932892519336933993279337925693339324933192609333932992759264933093489340935093389270935593389338933993539276936693609350928093579348935592849366935293619353926793239373936593759363929593809363936393649378930193719375936993059384937693749381937593929312939193799396931693989400938994029390939393239400939193989305936194119403941394019333941894019401940294169339943094199430942593449421941294199348942994199427936493539419943794299439942793599444942794279428944293659436944594449369945494379438945494539451945893559411946194539463945193839468945194519452946693899461947394819482939494739396948694849481940094799467948494049490947894769479940994869477948493919392945794989424949195019420950994879489949894909426950995069509951594319498950495199517950594379521950595099441951295099444953495129512953294279494951795249522945495409538953595279530946795319462954295469547953194679546954995559557953795579474955495489548947895559546955394899552956694859557955395549489956095769568949395659561949695679576957595009587957394819558957095769593958995919510958595949513959395819587960295189607958595879596952395989610960495989535959995309610961496159599953596209603962496049624954196089608952295879628954796369614961696259552962496399637955696419636964996429561964096289645956596409649957596389652957196569639963996409654957796459668965896579582966996559563956496339653967095909677967595939670966196689597967696699688960196929685960496909672968196089663961797019612969696969697970597039683970395989670968896889631969696269698971097189719963197229715963497119702970996459708972296419713970997109645972597369734971497319651972397199654972597389739963696379693974397359745973396659750973397339734974896719756975997479757967697539744975196809753974996959684975097689760977097589690977597589758975997739696978697809770970097779768977597049786977297819773968797439793978597959783971598009783978397849798972197919795978997259804979697949801979598129732981197999816973698189820980998229810981397439820981198189725978198319823983398219753983898219821982298369759985098399850984597649841983298399768984998399847978497739839985798499859984797799864984798479848986297859856986598649789987498579858987498739871987897759831988198739883987198039888987198719872988698099881989399019902981498939816990699049901982098999887990498249910989898969899982999069897990498119812986899189910992099089840992599089908990999239846993199349922993298519928991999269855992899249870985999259943993599459933986599509933993399349948987199619955994598759952994399509879996199479956994898629918996899609970995898909975995899589959997398969966997099649900997999719969997699709987990799869974999199119993999599849997998599889918999599869993990099569100699989100899969928910139996999699979101199349102591014910259102099399101691007910149943910249101491022995999489101491032910249103491022995491039910229102291023910379960910319104091039996491049910329103391049910489104691053995091006910569104891058910469978910639104691046910479106199849105691068910769107799899106899919108191079910769995910749106291079999991085910739107191074910049108191072910799986998791018910459107891098910149109991102910909110091019910969108791094910239109691092910359100591036910639109691116910329111791120911089111891037911149110591112910419111491110910539102391054910819111491134910599105191085911359112791137911259105791142911259112591126911409106391148911519113991149910809106991135911539114591155911439107591160911439114391144911589108191166911699115791167910869109591172911759116391173910929116991160911679109691169911659110891078911099113691169911899111491106911409119091182911929118091112911979118091180911819119591118912039120691194912049113591124911909120891200912109119891130912159119891198911999121391136912219122491212912229114191150912279123091218912289114791224912159122291151912249122091163911339113491199912409116691233912439116291251912299123191240912329116891251912489125191257911739124091246912619125991247911799126391247912519118391254912519118691276912549125491274911699123691259912669126491196912829128091277912699127291209912739120491284912889128991273912099128891291912979129991279912999121691296912909129091220912979128891295912319129491308912279129991295912969123191302913189131091235913079130391238913099131891317912429132991315912239130091312913189133591331913339125291327913369125591335913239132991344912609134991327913299133891265913409135291346913409127791341912729135291356913579134191277913629134591366913469136691283913509135091264913299137091289913789135691358913679129491366913819137991298913839137891391913849130391382913709138791307913829139191317913809139491313913989138191381913829139691319913879141091400913999132491411913979130591306913839133091418914049140391405913359141091415914039141091340914129140891343914159142791435914369134891425914169142391352914389142091429913569141191365914499136091444914449144591453914519143191451913469142191436914429144391451913749146591454914659146091379914569144791454913839145691450914679146991457914599146191469914579147491372913739142991479914719148191469914019148691469914699147091484914079149291495914839149391412914899148091487914169148991485914319142091486915049149691506914949142691511914949149491495915099143291522915169150691436915139150491511914409152291508915179150991423914799152991521915319151991451915369151991519915209153491457915279153191525914619154091532915309153791531915489146891547915359155291472915549155691545915589154691549914799155691547915549146191517915679155991569915579148991574915579155791558915729149591586915759158691581915009157791568915759150491585915759158391520915099157591593915859159591583915159160091583915839158491598915219159291601916009152591610915939159491610916099160791614915119156791617916099161991607915399162491607916079160891622915459161791629916379163891550916299155291642916409163791556916359162391640915609164691634916329163591565916429163391640 (I've warned you.)
```

**Edit: I forgot to tell the key to decrypt the cipher, so here it is (for anyone who wanted to do it, of course):**

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABAAAAAAABABAAAAAAABAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAABAAAAABAAABABAAABAAAAAABAABABAAABAAAABAAAAAABAAABAAAABAAABAABAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAABAAAAAAABABAABAAAAAAABAABAABABAAABAAAAAABABAAAABABABAABABAAAAABAABABABAAAABABAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAABAABABABAABAABAABABAAABABAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABAAAAAABAABABAAAABAABABAABAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAABAABAAAAABAAAABAAABABAAAABABAABAABAAABAABABABAABAABAAABAABAAAAAABAAABAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAABAAAABAAABAAAAAAAAAAABABABAAABAABAAAAAAAABAABAAABAABBAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAABAAAAAAAABAAAAAABABAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAABAAABAAAABAABAAABAAABAAAAAAAABABABAAAAABAAAAABAABAAABAAAAAAABAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAABAAAABAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAABABAAAAAAABAAAABAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABAAAAAAABAABABABAAABABAABAAAABBAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABAAAAAABAABABAAAABAABABAABAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABABABAABAABABABAABBAABAABABABABBABABABABAAAABABABABAABABABABBABAABABABABAABABBABAABABAABABABABABABAABABABABABAABABABAABABABABABABABABAABABABABABABABABABABBABABABABABABABBABABBABABABABABABABBABABBABBABABBABABABABBABABBABABAABBAABBABAABBABBABBAABAAAAABBAAAABAAAABBABAAAAAABABAAAAABAAABABABAAABAAAABAAAAAABAAAAAABAAAAABBAABBAABAABBAAABABBBAAAAAAAABABABAAAABAABBAABAABABAABAABABAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABABAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAABAAAAABABAAABABAAAABAABABAAAABAABAAABAAAABAAAABAAAABAAAABAAABABABBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABAAAAAAAAAAAABAABAAABAAAABAABAAAAABAABAABABABBABABBAABABABAABAABAABAAABBABABAAAAAAAAABAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAABAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABAAAAABAAABABAAABAAAAAAAABAAABAABAAAABABAAAABBAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAABAABAABAAAAABABAAABAAABABAAAABABAABAABAAAABAAAAAABAABAAABABABABAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABABAAABAAABABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABABAAAAAAABABAABAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAABAABAAAAAAABAABAAAAABABAABAAAAAABABAABAAAAAAAABAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: Somehow I have the feeling that the final answer will be a rickroll.

Comment: A base 10 number that doesn't translate to ascii needs hints of what the cipher is about

Comment: (@Varun W.) "https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do" -> "Thank you - I'll avoid that"

Comment: @ralphmerridew good call man

Comment: Do not worry.  I will not try to decrypt this encrypted string with a line of numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Per the instructions,

> I did not decrypt the string. I did notice it says "(I've warned you.)" at the end of the long string of numbers - is that all we were supposed to notice? Or is there more to the puzzle?

So I came back to this one and decided to take a stab at it. It appears that

> the long string of numbers is a bunch of mostly 3- and 4-digit numbers separated by an instance of the digit 9. The solution is to remove all those 9-separators (but not the 9s that appear as part of an actual 3- or 4-digit number) so you have a long sequence of numbers. Then subtract from each number its position in the sequence (starting with 0).
>
> For example, the string starts:
>
> 74911594191049118937910391059409111911391129122911091309129911791199...
>
> which turns into:
>
> 74 115 41 104 118 37 103 105 40 111 113 112 122 110 130 129 117 119...
>
> which turns into:
>
> 74 114 39 101 114 32 97 98 32 102 103 101 110 97 116 114 101 102...
>
> You end up with a bunch of numbers, mostly in the range from 97-122, with a smaller number of them between 65-90, a bunch of 32s, some 10s, and a few others in the 39-45 range. You then do the obvious thing and convert these from ASCII codes into text, and realizing it still doesn't spell out anything legible, as a final step you ROT-13 the whole lot.

After doing all that, you realize that the solution is

> **"We're no strangers to love..."**

Comment: I think the "I warned you" means that the ciphertext is really long and that there is more to the puzzle than that meets the eye.

Comment: rot13("Be vf gurer zber gb gur chmmyr?" -> "Gurer vf zber gb gur chmmyr; jneavatf ner vagraqrq sbe qrzbafgengvba bayl.")

Comment: You know the rules...